# jenkinsfile copy surefire report to Nexus

Tags: jenkins, nexus

I'm looking a way to copy from jenkins instance a pdf report file (surefire.pdf) to nexus. 
I don't need to copy the artifact, but only a generic pdf file via jenkinsfile.

I was checking the *nexusArtifactUploader* plugin but I'm not sure if it is the correct one as it seems to be only for "*artifacts*", while I need to upload just a pdf file.

Could you pls indicate to me a plugIn that I can use to copy a pdf file to Nexus via jenkinsfile?

Thanks.